# Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), XYZ.class) null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent

The problem i'm facing is , When i want to move to new activity i'm facing an null pointer exception,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at my.packname.fragments.CustomClass.handleResponse(Unknown Source:209)
   at my.packname.controllers.CustomClassController$1.onResponse(Unknown Source:114)
   at my.packname.controllers.CustomClassController$1.onResponse(Unknown Source:70)
   at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(Unknown Source:72)
   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(Unknown Source:99)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

My Code is,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), XYZ.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |   intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what is this line of code `CustomClass.handleResponse(Unknown Source:209`

Comment: Are you writing this code in activity or in fragment?

Comment: you are using the code in fragment ?

Comment: in line CustomClass.handleResponse(Unknown Source:209)   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), XYZ.class)

Comment: yes i am using this code in Fragment

Comment: show your XYZ.class code

Comment: @Sumit check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046394/java-lang-nullpointerexception-and-unknown-source)

Comment: XYZ.class extends AppCompatActivity where i take mobile number , email and password no thing else

Answer (score -1):

try This

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), XYZ.class));
```

Comment: ok I will this code, but are you sure it can fix the issue ? because it's very rare case and crash in Motorola Moto E OS 4.4.4 and i can't reproduce it.